# Determining correct Coordinate System DHDN Bessel 1841

Tags: coordinate-system

I am working on a data set and coordinates are supposed to be in DHDN Bessel 1841.
Have a look here: https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/gast/stammdaten?pegelnr=2330013

I created a shapefile with the cordinates. But I need to define the projection. I am using qgis and when I checked DHDN options, there were a lot like DHDN/ Gauss-Kruger 2,3,4,5 or DHDN/ 3-degree gauss zone 1,2,3,4,5. I am confused which one to use.

Some insight will be of great help.

Thanks

NS

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset](http://www.epsg-registry.org) in its online registry form. You can search DHDN and see what projected coordinate reference systems are based upon it. Some quick notes. The first set you listed are 6-degree wide zones. The 2nd set are 3-degree wide zones. The listed coordinates are probably in northing,easting order. That implies to me that it's zone 3, but whether the 6- or 3-degree is the question. Northing values should be around 5million.

Disclaimer: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the registry.

Comment: Yeah. Cordinates are northing-easting and northing values are around 5 mil. But still 6-degree or 3-degree?
Also, thanks a lot for the link. But it shows different systems, how do I know which one is mine?

Comment: You (and I) can only made educated guess without further information. One way is to somehow find lat/lon coordinates for the point. Another way is to assume the point is in a coordinate reference system, convert it to lat/lon. Is the lat/lon correct? If no, try another coordinate reference system.

Answer (score 1):

The "pegelnummer" has changed and now might be moved to https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/gast/stammdaten?pegelnr=23300130

On the site, you read:

```
Koordinate (Gauss-Krüger 3, Bessel 1841, DHDN)  Rechtswert: 3.389.712,75; Hochwert: 5.286.907,74
```

This is EPSG:31467, which has always Eastings starting with 3. The 6-degrees Gauß-Krüger projections were not used in Germany under the name of DHDN. There are some other DHDN systems listed too, but all have identical projection definition strings.